# How can I get a Media Element Mp3 player to stop playing when another mp3 starts to play?

Tags: mediaelement.js

How can I stop an mp3 from playing when another starts playing?

I have several mp3s embedded in one file, I need for one player to stop when another player starts playing. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The `pauseOtherPlayers: true`, option should work:

```
$('audio,video').mediaelementplayer({
    //mode: 'shim',
    pauseOtherPlayers: true,
    features: ['progress','current','duration'],
    alwaysShowControls: true,
    alwaysShowHours: false,
    success: function(player, node) {
        $('#' + node.id + '-mode').html('mode: ' + player.pluginType);
    }
});

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help on this Stephen :)